# how do I define a vector that is perpendicular to my direction of travel and and direction of planet?

Tags: math, vector, lua

situation: I am trying to produce navigation markers to populate a hud nav ball, I have prograde and retrograde and radial in and out by taking my heading and -heading vector and vector to planet and -planet vector respectively.

goal: I need to define normal and anti-normal, as there is no defined north/south on a planetoid in this system I am just looking for the normal/anti-normal vectors to be arbitrarily left and right with prograde being forward.

thank you for any and all assistance

Comment: See [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)

Comment: cross product was most of the answer, ended up adding some filters as the game was having some display  trouble when heading was not an orbit vector